# Retrieve authorization code from Redirect URL

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use the Destiny 2 API and retrieve information that is sent from their API and being new to OAuth2 retrieving the authorization code is where I have hit a wall.

I have this code:

```
async function get(url, callback) {

    var clientID = process.env.BUNGIE_CLIENTID;
    var authorizationCode = 'CODE_GOES_HERE';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/App/OAuth/Token/", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-API-Key", process.env.BUNGIE_API);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("client_id="+ clientID + "&grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + authorizationCode);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
       callback.apply(xhr);
    }
};
```

which will send me the access token required to access certain information in the Destiny API. However, with this code I will have to manually retrieve the authorization code from a redirect URL when a user approves my application, which will not cut it. The destiny API documentation if vague, like many other sources on OAuth2, stating "get the authorization code".

From what I have learnt the user will approve the application and then be redirected to a redirect URL with

"?code={authorization code}"

appended onto the end of the URL. I do not know where to start on getting this code from the URL. I believe a server will be need, which can be set up, but other than that I don’t know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an OAuth flow, the browser is redirected to the redirect URI, so in fact you visit the page which can be found under your redirect URI. As you've noted the authorization code will be appended to the redirect URI as part of the query string.

You have two options:

1. You can have a backend service, so a server, which listens on your redirect URI. There you would have a controller processing the request sent to the redirect URI, which can read the query string - thus the authorization code, then perform a request for a token (like you've described in your example), then do something with the access token it got. E.g. you can save the access token in a database together with a session identifier, so anytime the user sends a request with a session cookie, you can read the access token from the database to access the API.
2. You can have a frontend app under the redirect URI. Then you can run the code you pasted in your browser. You can use javascript to get the query string of the current page (e.g. by calling `window.location.search` and then splitting the string using `&` as the delimiter). When you get the access token, you can store it in memory or in the local storage, so it can be used by your frontend app.

Comment: What I don't understand about this is why the initial response returns 200 instead of 301 or 302. Because if it redirects it should be possible to get the redirected URL from a Microsoft ActiveX HTTP object via the property .Option(WinHttpRequestOption_URL) or .GetResponseHeader("Location")

Answer (score 0):

This is a VBA solution using the IE library:

```
Function GetAuthCodeIE(myURL As String) As String
    Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Long = 4
    
    Dim oIE As Object
    
    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    Call oIE.Navigate(myURL)
    
    While oIE.Busy Or oIE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
    Dim Response As String
    Response = oIE.LocationURL
    
    Dim aResponse() As String
    aResponse = Split(Response, "?")
    
    aResponse = Split(aResponse(1), "&")
    GetAuthCodeIE = Replace(aResponse(0), "code=", "")
End Function
```